# How would you use map on a list of tuples that contains a list of tuples?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I have a list here that has the following structure:

```
list = [((1,1),[("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]), ((2,2),[("B", 2)]), ((3,3),[("C",3)])]
```

I want to output a list that has the following structure (aka summing the values of each of the second values of each sublist so for example (1+4+5) = 10

```
[((1,1),10), ((2,2),2), ((3,3),3))]
```

I am not sure how to get that structure by using map or even filter and the closest I have gotten is:

```
map snd (concat (map snd list))
```

which produces `[1,4,5,2,3]`

How would I achieve this structure?

Answer (score 1):

First, write out the types:

```
have :: [((Int,Int), [(String,Int)])]
have = [ ((1,1),[("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]), ... ]

want :: [((Int,Int), Int)]
```

Evidently, the `(Int,Int)` isn't really relevant here, nor is the `String`. So our conversion function can be

```
give :: [(a, [(b, Int)])] -> [(a, Int)]
```

Furthermore, the `a` is just passed as-is, so the interesting bit is going to be `[(b, Int)] -> Int`. For this, you first need to throw away the `b`s

```
Prelude> map snd [("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]
[1,4,5]
```

and sum the result (composition!)

```
Prelude> sum . map snd $ [("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]
10
```

So `sum . map snd` is the function you'll need to apply to every RHS in the list of outer tuples.

How do you actually use it on only the RHS? Well, one way is to write a lambda

```
   \(x,y) -> (x, f y)
```

...but actually there's a standard combinator for this, called [`second`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second)

```
second :: (b -> c) -> (d,b) -> (d,c)
```

(operating on the `snd` element of a tuple, applying a function<sup>†</sup> to it, putting it back in the tuple).

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> second (sum . map snd) (346, [("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)])
(346,10)
```

All that's left to do is mapping that whole thing over the outer list:

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> map (second $ sum . map snd) [((1,1),[("A", 1), ("D", 4), ("E", 5)]), ((2,2),[("B", 2)]), ((3,3),[("C",3)])]
[((1,1),10),((2,2),2),((3,3),3)]
```

Or as a definition

```
give :: Num c => [(a, [(b, c)])] -> [(a, c)]
give = map . second $ sum . map snd
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>If you look in the docs you'll find that `second` is actually more general than that: it can work not only with functions, but general arrows `~>`, i.e. `second :: Arrow (~>) => (b ~> c) -> ((d,b)~>(d,c))`. If that's confusing to you, don't worry... in most applications, the arrow will just be the normal function one.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the `map` you could use list comprehension here:

```
list = [((1,1),[("A",1),("D",4),("E",5)]),((2,2),[("B",2)]),((3,3),[("C",3)])]
[(fst x, sum [snd y | y <- (snd x) ]) | x <- list]
```

returns

```
[((1,1),10),((2,2),2),((3,3),3)]
```

Comment: List comprehension is a good option, but then you should pattern-match the `fst` and `snd`.